# Pandas, groupby absolute month

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, group-by, dataframe

*Question*: Given a data frame with several entries and a "date" column of the form %Y%m%d (i.e. yyyy-mm-dd; these entries come as strings) what is a computationally-fast way to way add a column to the data frame consisting of the lexicographic order on the months?

*Why on StackOverflow*: Given a specified year and month, the above ordering allows one to easily go up or down any number of months relative to the specified month. I have a working ad hoc solution, but imagine this problem has been solved elegantly before.

*Context*: By way of example, given the data frame df:

```
         date  user
0  2011-10-06     1
1  2011-09-01     2
2  2011-11-05     3
3  2012-01-01     1
4  2012-01-01     2
5  2012-01-02     3
```

the desired output is:

```
         date  user  absmonth
0  2011-10-06     1         2
1  2011-09-01     2         1
2  2011-11-05     3         3
3  2012-01-01     1         4
4  2012-01-01     2         4
5  2012-01-02     3         4
```

*What I've tried*:

1) I made an adhoc def that sets the value of 'absmonth' based on simple arithmetic; via `df.loc[row, 'absmonth'] = ...` for each row. This "works" but is computationally *very* slow.

2) Using groupby:

```
df['newdate']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y-%m-%d') 
df = df.set_index('newdate')
monthsgroup = df.groupby(df.index.month, df.index.year)
```

which produces the error:

```
    axis = self._AXIS_ALIASES.get(axis, axis)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

and also:

```
months = df.gropuby(df.index.month)
len(months)
4
```

At this point, I should be able to use something like an "apply" function on `df` using `months`, but am a bit lost...

ps:

```
pd.__version__
'0.14.0'
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: not sure what you mean by lexagraphic order of months?   Is that the month spelled out in English sorted alphabetically?

Comment: lexicographic on the set of all number pairs (Y, m). I.e. We write "(Y,m) < (Y', m')" if and only if the following holds as natural numbers: either i) Y < Y' or ii) Y = Y' and m < m'. If both of these conditions are not met, we write (Y,m) = (Y',m').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 'apply' is a good way to go.

I provide my current solution from start to finish. I think I've fixed the ranking by now applying the method 'min' in order to get the desired result.

```
import pandas as pd

x = [{'date':'2011-10-06', 'user':1}, {'date':'2011-09-01', 'user':2},{'date':'2011-11-05', 'user':3}, {'date':'2012-01-01', 'user':1},{'date':'2012-01-01', 'user':2}, {'date':'2012-01-02', 'user':3}]

dx = pd.DataFrame(x)

dx['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dx['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

def get_ym(s):
  s = str(s)
  s = s[:7]
  s = s.replace('-','')
  return int(s)


dx['absmonth'] = dx['date'].apply(get_ym)
dx['absmonth'] = dx['absmonth'].rank(method='min')

-----
dx = 
        date  user  absmonth
0 2011-10-06     1  2
1 2011-09-01     2  1
2 2011-11-05     3  3
3 2012-01-01     1  4
4 2012-01-01     2  4
5 2012-01-02     3  4
```

If someone has a slicker solution, e.g. using groupby, I'm all ears.

UPDATE:
DSM kindly suggested the following solution, which is a compact version of my approach *and* ranks in increments of 1 by using 'dense':

```
dx['absmonth'] = dx['date'].str.split('-').str[:2].rank('dense')
```

Comment: Hey, you deleted my recommendation. :-)  We should probably use `dense` instead of `min` as the rank method, i.e. `df["date"].str.split("-").str[:2].rank("dense")` to handle the case you noticed.  With that it'll increment by 1 each time.

Comment: oh, sorry, I thought you had deleted, my apologies!

Comment: I needed it a while back, so I [added it](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6514). :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
df['absmonth'] = df.date
dict = df.absmonth.unique()
dict.sort()
df.absmonth.replace(dict,range(1,len(dict)+1),inplace=True)
```

**Edit** If you prefer to work with dates instead to format at the end:

```
df['absmonth'] = df.date.apply(lambda x: np.datetime64(x, 'M'))
dict = df.absmonth.unique()
dict.sort()
df.absmonth.replace(dict,range(1,len(dict)+1),inplace=True)
df.absmonth=df.absmonth.astype(int)
```

I think a way should exist to avoid the use of apply but I didn't find it.
Pandas.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y-%m-%d',unit='M') doesn't work for me.
However, I hope it accomplishes what you want.

Comment: Your solutions do not work precisely because you sort by the entire date triples (Y, m, d) and *do not* perform the parsing necessary to sort by pairs (Y,m). To do the latter, I think groupby (or join) may be best. Also note: on pandas 14.0 and with the setup i mentioned, your edited solution does not work unfortuntaley: TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike [datetime64[ns]] to [int32].

Comment: if it helps: in the result of your first proposal, the last entry in the `absmonth` column, i.e. for the row with `date = 2012-01-02` is `5`, it should be `4`.

Comment: Ok got it, I didn't realize that

Comment: thanks for your comments; in the future please produce the results of your proposals so people can analyze/confirm :-)

Comment: ps: as I found a solution earlier, and verified it, and DSM provided an improvement, I'm going to elect my solution as "accepted". thanks again for the comments though, always good to consider different ideas.